# Express when festivity or event happens

Tags: grammar, greetings

I need to write an eassy about festivities and I included the following sentence:

> 公历每年十二月十五日是这个西方传统的节日。

The teacher said this was not correct Chinese, instead, I should have written:

> 圣诞节这个西方传统节日**在**每年的十二月二十五日。

I also saw other examples in the book.

> 圣诞节是在每年的十二月十五日。Festivity + 是在每年的 + date.  中秋节**是**农历八月五日。Festivity 是 +
>   date. 中国的春天一般**在**一月底到二月初。 Chinese Festivity + 在 date.

So I am a bit confused. From what I learned:

**1) It seems that you cannot first put the date and then 的 festivity.**

**2) You can put the event and then 是在，是，and 在 and after that, the date.**

Are these two assumptions correct?

Saludos desde España.

Comment: I don't believe that what you wrote is equivalent to the examples that you gave. You wrote (shortened, paraphrased): "December 25th is this Traditional Western Holiday". To be honest, this isn't a natural English expression either (I would write: "This Traditional Western Holiday lies on December 25th"). If you were trying to say directly that "December 25th is Christmas Day", then 十二月二十五日是聖誕節 is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can put the event before or after the date.

> When you write the name of an event first, you can add the information of **when** this event occurs.
>
> Example: [圣诞节] [**是在**] [十二月二十五日] = [Christmas] [**is on**] [25th December]

~

> When you write a date first, you can add the information of **what** this date represents
>
> Example: [十二月二十五日] [**是**] [圣诞节] = [25th December] [**is**] [Christmas]

More example:

我的生日是在日十二月二十五日 - My birthday is on December 25th.

十二月二十五日是我的生日 - December 25th is my birthday

- When you are describing "when the event occurs", you can omit "在" and write "圣诞节是十二月二十五日" (Christmas is 25th December) or "我的生日是十二月二十五日" (My birthday is 25th December)
- When you are describing "what the date represents", you cannot add "在"  and write  "十二月二十五日是在圣诞节" (25th December is on Christmas) or "十二月二十五日是在我的生日" (25th December is on my birthday )
- You can add more information about the date. "十二月二十五日" just means "25th December" ; "每年的十二月二十五日" means "25th December of every year"

Comment: I suposse in teh second Parragraph  it would be  you can add "在" instead of cannot add.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @ANTXON I meant you cannot. 十二月二十五日是(在)我的生日 is ungrammatical

Answer (score 0):

What you have is good:

圣诞节这个西方传统节日在每年的十二月二十五日。

but you can shift it around:

每年的十二月二十五号是西方的传统节日——圣诞节。

I think you may use 是、在、是在, como quieras.

¡Recuerdos desde China a mi querida Andalucía!

Comment: Recuerdos desde Benalmádena Málaga.

Comment: Vaya, no me digas! El verano estaba en Málaga, comiendo espetos!

Comment: Jjjj cuando quieras practicar español  y yo chino hablamos. 你为什么离开马拉加？

Comment: 我的中文太差，更好找到中国人帮你。Fuimos a Grazalema, Jerez y Cadiz. Solo estaba 2 dias en Malaga.